# Sort Manufacturer's attribute by their "position"

Tags: magento-1.7, backend, attributes, frontend

I'm trying to sort manufacturer's attribute option values by their "position" as entered in the backend, in attributes' panel. I need to get, for example all the manufacturers with position 2, or all the manufacturers with position 1 etc., by specifying it in the code below.

I've tried ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_position', array('eq'=> 200)); in the code below, but it isn't working. (btw this is the only of the 3 codes that actually is working.)

```
<?php
  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
  $attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
  ->setEntityTypeFilter($product->getResource()->getTypeId())
  ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', 'manufacturer');
  $attribute = $attributes->getFirstItem()->setEntity($product->getResource());
  $manufacturers = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
?>

<div id="brandz">
<?php 
$rows = array_chunk($manufacturers, 6);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
?>

<ul class="rapper">
<?php foreach ($row as $manufacturer) { ?>
<li>
<a href=""><?php echo $manufacturer['label'] ?></a>
</li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

I've also tried this:

```
<?php
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load( $code, 'attribute_code');
$option_col = Mage::getResourceModel( 'eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
 ->setAttributeFilter( $attribute->getId() )
 ->setStoreFilter()
 ->setPositionOrder( 'ASC' );
$option_col->getSelect()->order('main_table.sort_order '.$orderby);
?>
```

but it isn't working, also, for me.

I was also suggested to do it this way (but it still won't work)

```
<?php
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load('manufacturer', 'attribute_code');

    $manufacturers = Mage::getResourceModel( 'eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
     ->setAttributeFilter($attribute->getId())
     ->addFieldToFilter('sort_order', 1)
     ->unshiftOrder('sort_order', 'ASC')
     ->setStoreFilter();
?>

<div id="brandz">
<?php 
    $rows = array_chunk($manufacturers, 6);
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
?>

<ul class="rapper"><?php foreach ($row as $manufacturer) { ?>
    <li><a href=""><?php echo $manufacturer['label'] ?></a></li>
<?php } ?></ul><?php } ?>
</div>
```

Do you have any ideas how could it be done?

Answer (score 2):

I think i can help you here.

What i can see here is you need something like brands listing which are configured as an attribute i.e manufacturer in back-end so that when admin sets the manufacturer for the product that product appears when some one click on that manufacturer's label and before that all the manufacturers are listed.

If there is anything more tell me i will provide you the code snippet here. Also tell me how far you have reached.

Comment: Yes, as you said I need to list brands which are configured as attributes in my case (manufacturer) in backend, but I need them to show by position.
i.e. I gave 10 manufacturers the position 1, to other 10 the position 2, etc. I only want to show those that are with postion 1. 

I'm doing this because I run a multisite and need to have only 1 attribute (manufacturer). and in this case I'm able for site one to get only the 10 brandz with position 1 and for site 2 those with position 2 and so on... http://i.imgur.com/IgxNeiv.png

Comment: ohk great!! then how you are assigning them position ? you should print the array of attribute and see is there is any key of position because you need to put a check on position.

Comment: in the backend when editing the manufacturer's attribute ( Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > Manufacturer > Manage Label / Options ) there's a position field along with the others. I thought to use that.. http://i.imgur.com/IgxNeiv.png

Comment: May be i missed some thing you have made some custom module in which you are assigning the position to your manufacturer and your manufacturer attribute is a dropdown at admin. if it is like this then check where your position value is stored in database then after getting the values from the attribute collection we just put a check of position.

Comment: yes, but if it is not used the position thing how can I separate the manufacturers from site 1 and site 2, so the manufacturers from site 1 to do not appear on site 2 and vice versa?? I don't see other ways..

Comment: I'm confused right now! hahaha

Comment: hahaha no need to get confused it happens !!

Comment: so, it can't be done with the position as it is? Any other ways?

Comment: We will use the position you set for sure but you need to find out where it is saved in database

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
              ->setEntityTypeFilter($product->getResource()->getTypeId())
              ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', 'manufacturer');
  $attribute = $attributes->getFirstItem()->setEntity($product->getResource());
  $manufacturers = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
  foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer): 
  // here you need put a check something like : 
     if ( manufacturer has position 0) :
    do ........ 
    //
   endforeach;
     ?>
```

Now you just need to find out where the position thing is saved in database and it is done.

Comment: I found it... 
it is in: **eav_attribute_option** and it got the name of **sort_order**

Comment: what should I do with it now?!